# window.open working at will

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function search(newWindow){
    var searchInput = $("#searchField").attr('value');
    var link = "foobar/"+searchInput;
    if(newWindow){
        window.open(link, '_blank');
    }else{
        window.open(link, '_self');
    }   
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchField").on('keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            search(false);
        }
    });
    $("#searchButton").on('click', function(e) {
        var newWindow = false;
        if(e.ctrlKey){
            newWindow = true;
        }
        search(newWindow);
    });
});
```

I am creating a code which tries to behave like a link while looking like a button. The request was to be able to click on the button and open on a new window or on the same window, so i'm using the ctrl as a parameter to determine which action the program will take.

The following test cases are needed.

**Type on "searchField" and press enter.**
Expected Result: open the link on the same page
Obtained Result: the link is opened on the same page

**Type on "searchField" and click on link**
Expected Result: open the link on the same page
Obtained Result: the page blinks, and the page is not loaded

**Type on "searchField and press ctrl, then click on link**
Expected Result: open the link on a new page
Obtained Result: the link is opened on a new page

Ok, so turns out that both methods (clicking on the link and pressing enter) are using the same method, which is **search(false)**, but one is working and the other is not. Why?

I've already tried using window.location.href, i've already tried to debug the code

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Except for `window.location.href = link;` in `else`, looks (and works) fine:

```js
function search(newWindow) {
  var searchInput = $("#searchField").attr('value');
  var link = "./foobar/" + searchInput;
  if (newWindow) {
    window.open(link, '_blank');
  } else {
    window.location.href = link; // <<<
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchField").on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      search(false);
    }
  });
  $("#searchButton").on('click', function(e) {
    var newWindow = false;
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
      newWindow = true;
    }
    search(newWindow);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<div>
  <form>
    <label for="searchField">Search:</label>
    <input type="text" id="searchField" name="searchField" />
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="searchButton">Go</a>
  </form>
</div>
```